# Emalator and Phone Shows More Icons for one application?

Tags: android, emulation

can any body tell me the solution for this , my problem is when run the application i my emulator in menu it display's more icons nearly 18 icons for one application. tell me the solution for this.

**Edit Ans:**

I defined each activity the main and launch property, because of that i got every activity being shown as an icon in the applications.

Comment: is that application developed by you...

Comment: yes in my app only, with small icon's

Comment: please post your AndroidManifest.xml file

Comment: yes, i got it my problem in Manifext file only, thank's every one for reply

Comment: that's good.. i think you might have defined each activity the main and launch property... am i right? because of which you got every activity being shown as an icon in the applications.....

Comment: @Dinash  yes u r right i done mistake in activity main and launch property.

Comment: i Edited my question now with answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are just shortcuts which appear on the desktop, then left click on each one and drag it down to the bottom of the screen, where a 'trash can' icon will appear. Dump them in that.

Comment: even in phone also it show's like that , and once if it delete again i run the application it show's